# If MonadPlus is the "generator" class, then what is the "consumer" class?

Tags: loops, haskell, category-theory, haskell-pipes, monadplus

A `Pipe` can be broken into two parts: the *generator* part (`yield`) and the *consumer* part (`await`).

If you have a `Pipe` that only uses it's generator half, and only returns `()` (or never returns), then it can be represented as a "`ListT` done right". It turns out that `MonadPlus` can be used to represent anything like ListT-done-right. [Quoting Gabriel Gonzalez](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/2bpsh7/a_simple_monadic_stream_library/cj7sqtw?context=3):

> Note that you can build any `ListT` (not just the one in pipes) with only a transformers dependency. For example, here is how you would implement a `ListT` analog of `Pipes.Prelude.stdinLn`:
>
> ```
> -- stdinLn :: ListT IO String
> stdinLn :: (MonadTrans t, MonadPlus (t IO)) => t IO String
> stdinLn = do
>     eof <- lift isEOF
>     if eof
>         then mzero
>         else do
>             str <- lift getLine
>             return str `mplus` stdinLn
> ```
>
> That will type check as any `ListT` out there and do the right thing for all of them.

So my question is this: Is there a dual to `ListT` and to `MonadPlus` for the consumer portion of Pipes?

Requirements:

- A pipe which never uses `yield`, and only returns `()` (or never returns), but does use `await` can be represented as this "dual to ListT".
- The "dual to ListT" can be generalized to the "dual of MonadPlus"

Comment: I would think that would be something like `FoldM`, but I haven't thought about it too much.

Comment: Maybe it's [SupplyT](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-supply-0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Supply.html#t:SupplyT) ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the answer is not to dualize the "generator-like" type-class, but rather to extend it with a simple `Category` instance equivalent to the `await`/`(>~)` category of `pipes`.

Unfortunately, there is no way to arrange the type variables to make this satisfy all three type classes (`MonadPlus`, `MonadTrans`, and `Category`), so I will define a new type class:

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}

import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class

class Consumer (t :: * -> (* -> *) -> * -> *) where
    await :: t a m a
    (>~)  :: t a m b -> t b m c -> t a m c
```

The laws for this type class are the category laws:

```
await >~ f = f

f >~ await = f

(f >~ g) >~ h = f >~ (g >~ h)
```

Then you can implement both `Consumer`s and `Pipe`s once you have this additional type class:

```
printer :: (Show a, Monad (t a IO), MonadTrans (t a), Consumer t) => t a IO r
printer = do
    a <- await
    lift (print a)
    printer
{-
printer :: Show a => Consumer a IO r
printer = do
    a <- await
    lift (print a)
    printer
-}

cat :: (MonadPlus (t a m), Consumer t) => t a m a
cat = await `mplus` cat
{-
cat :: Monad m => Pipe a a m r
cat = do
    a <- await
    yield a
    cat
-}

debug :: (Show a, MonadPlus (t a IO), MonadTrans (t a), Consumer t) => t a IO a
debug = do
    a <- await
    lift (print a)
    return a `mplus` debug
{-
debug :: Show a => Pipe a a IO r
debug = do
    a <- await
    lift (print a)
    yield a
    debug
-}

taker :: (Consumer t, MonadPlus (t a m)) => Int -> t a m a
taker 0 = mzero
taker n = do
    a <- await
    return a `mplus` taker (n - 1)
{-
taker :: Monad m => Int -> Pipe a a m ()
taker 0 = return ()
taker n = do
    a <- await
    yield a
    taker (n - 1)
-}
```

The hard part is figuring out how to do this without adding a new type class to `base`.  I'd prefer to reuse the original `Category` type class if possible, possibly having `await` and `(>~)` just be functions that wrap your type in a newtype, use the `Category` instance, and then unwrap it, but I'm still working out the specifics of how to do that.

Edit: I found the solution.  Just define the following newtype:

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures, FlexibleContexts #-}

import Control.Category
import Prelude hiding ((.), id)

newtype Consumer t m a b = Consumer { unConsumer :: t a m b }

await :: Category (Consumer t m) => t a m a
await = unConsumer id

(>~) :: Category (Consumer t m) => t a m b -> t b m c -> t a m c
f >~ g = unConsumer (Consumer f >>> Consumer g)
```

Then any library can just implement a `Category` instance for their type wrapped in the `Consumer` newtype.

Then you would get a constraint like this any time you used `await` or `(>~)`:

```
cat :: (MonadPlus (t a m), Category (Consumer t m)) => t a m a
cat = await `mplus` cat
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what I asked for, but I do want to mention that the `Category (Consumer t m)` idea is extremely cool.